# How to install anaconda python on debian 11 without breaking debian?

Tags: debian, installer-anaconda

I want to install anaconda from anaconda's website. They have provided an easy way to install on Linux via a shell script:
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

But I'm not sure **if it would go against the "don't break debian" rules** and **I fear if I break my debian :( again** ,
Would you please guide me on installing anaconda without breaking debian in next update/uprade. Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some more detail. First, why do you want to install from their website instead of using the Debian repositories? Are you 100% sure it is necessary? Second, what kind of breaking are you afraid of?

Comment: debian repositories doesnt contain anaconda . I've breaked debian so many times, so i afraid to install :( by looking any tutorial.